# Single device driver for multiple devices

Tags: linux-device-driver, fpga, xilinx

I'm writing a device driver for multiple devices, especially FPGA board.
I want a single driver to drive multiple devices.
In this case, how can I differentiate the devices in the code?
By minor number? PCIe address?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? Do you have an FPGA that contains multiple devices? (In this case: what bus connects SoC to FPGA and what bus connects in-FPGA blocks?) Or do you have multiple devices and a user can insert one of them at a time?

Comment: By minor number, by PCIe address, etc. Your question is too broad right now, you have to provide more specifics.